# Having an issue running map without exception googleMaps&Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Each time I'm trying to open map I'm getting this error

I have no clue why this is happening

And I search online for a solution though have not found one yet

It also says- The following assertion was thrown building CreateMapMarker(dirty, state: _CreateMapMarkerState#6a02b):

Thanks for the help
Thanks for the helpThanks for the help

```
'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/camera.dart': Failed assertion: line 26 pos 16: 'target != null': is not true.
```

---

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
class CreateMapMarker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateMapMarkerState createState() => _CreateMapMarkerState();
}

class _CreateMapMarkerState extends State<CreateMapMarker> {
      @override
        void initState(){
          super.initState();
          doSomeAsyncStuff();

        }
   Future<void> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
   Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currloc){
            setState((){
              _center = LatLng(currloc.latitude,currloc.longitude);
            });
          });
}


  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
   static  LatLng _center;
    bool _isChecked = true;
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {

        Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currloc){
          _center = LatLng(currloc.latitude,currloc.longitude);
        });
    _controller.complete(controller);

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return MaterialApp(

          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Center(child:Text('Create Marker')),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            ),
            body: GoogleMap(
              markers: _markers,
              onTap: _handleTap,
                        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                          target: _center,
                          zoom: 11.0,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }

                _handleTap(LatLng point) {
                setState(() {

                  _markers.add(Marker(

                    markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
                    position: point,
                    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: 'I am a marker',
                    ),

                    icon:
                        BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
                    onTap:()=> showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: this.context, 
                      builder: (builder){
                        return Container(
                          child:Center(
                            child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Enter name',

                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Enter type',

                              ),
                            ),
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text("Active ?"),
                              value: _isChecked,
                              onChanged: (newValue) { 
                                          setState(() {
                                            _isChecked = newValue; 
                                          }); 
                                        },
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,  //  <-- leading Checkbox
                            ),
                            ],
                            ),
                        ));  

                      }
                      )
                  )
                  );
                });
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because initially _center will be null since we are dealing with Future (i.e asynchronous operation). Moreover, the "initialCameraPosition" is used to set initial position of the map's camera. If you want to update the camera location after creating the map, then you can use the method "moveCamera" of the GoogleMapController instance. This is mainly used to Changes the map camera position. Have a look at the updated code below:

```
    class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MapPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  bool _isChecked = true;
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
  }

  Future<void> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currloc) {
      print("current location $currloc");
      if (currloc != null) {
        _controller.moveCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              bearing: 270.0,
              target: LatLng(currloc.latitude, currloc.longitude),
              tilt: 30.0,
              zoom: 17.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Create Marker')),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        markers: _markers,
        onTap: _handleTap,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
          zoom: 11.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _handleTap(LatLng point) {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
          position: point,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'I am a marker',
          ),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
              BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
          onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
              context: this.context,
              builder: (builder) {
                return Container(
                    child: Center(
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Enter name',
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Enter type',
                        ),
                      ),
                      CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text("Active ?"),
                        value: _isChecked,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _isChecked = newValue;
                          });
                        },
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity
                            .leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
              })));
       });
      }
      }
```

Comment: can you explain the purpose of "  MapPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
"

Comment: That is the Widget constructor. You can use it if you want to pass additional information to the widget from other widgets. You can also remove it and it will not cause any issue